# Cannot find the php_ini configuration file to find my error log to see why my code is not working

Tags: php, functions, javascript, errors

would anybody know where I could find the php_ini configuration file to look for error log, as my code will not work in wordpress.
I went to app folder, then public folder, but only see wp_config.php there.
I went into conf folder, then php folder which shows php.ini.hbs and php-fpm.conf.hbs files.
I looked in the wp config.php file, but there is nothing about an error log there.

Comment: Try `php --ini` at the command line. That list all the ini files that PHP reads, and is probably correct for mod_php unless you override settings in your web server config but I don't know if that's still the answer for FPM.

Comment: That said, look in your web server error log e.g. error_log or ssl_error_log in /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2 or similar. If you are running PHP FPM that might have a separate error log too. Or WordPress's own error log is the debug log which you [do configure in wp-config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: You've also tagged this JavaScript. You won't find JavaScript errors in your server logs.

Comment: Where will I find the command line, do I have to download linux first, as I have windows operating system.

Comment: Oh, OK - what are you using then, XAMPP? The ini files and logs will probably be somewhere in the XAMPP folder then, but I don't know XAMPP sorry. (Bottom entry of [the FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html) is "Where are the main XAMPP configuration files?") There will also be the PHP binary in there somewhere too.

Comment: I'm using local by flywheel. It enables me to have wordpress on my computer just like xampp.

Comment: OK, then you should look at the local by flywheel documentation for where the configuration files and logs are. Here's a link to a help article about logs: https://localwp.com/help-docs/troubleshooting/retrieving-locals-log-file/ although that might be the localwp-as-a-whole log not the actual PHP logs.